# How to write if statement and for loop?

Tags: programming

I am trying to write a function that will find a sum of all diagonal elements of matrix. I don't know how to do it correctly. This is how I tried do do it.

```
 matrix[n_, {rov_, column_}] := RandomInteger[n, {rov, column}]
matrix[10, {5, 5}]
For[sum = 0; i = 0, i < rov, i++;
 For[j = 0, j < column, j ++;
  If[i == j, sum = sum + matrix[10, {5, 5}]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

First I have written a function that generates matrix. And than I tried to write the function that will find the sum of diagonal elements.

Comment: Yep:  `Tr[A]` does it all.

Comment: Thx :). But if you know how to write a code I would be thankful

Comment: your code as written generates a new random matrix for each iteration of the loop. Is that what you want?

Comment: Your main problem (as written) is you have semicolons instead of commas after your increment in the for loop.

Comment: If you really don't want to use `Tr`, you could at least use `Total @* Diagonal`.

Comment: obligatory link https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/2079

Comment: Dear Geroge2079. I don't want to generate new matrix for each iteration. Do you know how to properly do it?

Answer (score 2):

*Let's have an answer so this question can be ticked off ...*

To calculate the sum of the elements on the main diagonal of a matrix use the intrinsic function `Tr`.   In  your case something like

```
Tr[matrix[10, {5, 5}]]
```

Before you use `For`, read the material @george2079 pointed you at.  If you are a beginner with *Mathematica* check out the documentation for `Tr` and follow the links to other related functions, do some discovery for yourself of what is already built in to the system.

In the code you've shown us you've made some slips in using `;` and `,` correctly in the `If` and `For` calls.  For someone whose mind has been over-influenced by C and its ilk the two punctuation marks might, on studying the *Mathematica* documentation, seem to be used the wrong way round.

As @george2079 has also pointed out your `matrix` is a function which, each time it is called, generates a new random matrix.  It doesn't make any sense to call it at each execution of the `If` statement inside the loop nest.  Perhaps you should write

```
mat1 = matrix[10, {5, 5}]
```

and then execute

```
Tr[mat1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(matrix = Array[a, {5, 5}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Tr[matrix]

(* a[1, 1] + a[2, 2] + a[3, 3] + a[4, 4] + a[5, 5] *)

Total@Diagonal@matrix

(* a[1, 1] + a[2, 2] + a[3, 3] + a[4, 4] + a[5, 5] *)

Total[matrix[[#, #]] & /@ Range[5]]

(* a[1, 1] + a[2, 2] + a[3, 3] + a[4, 4] + a[5, 5] *)

Total@Table[matrix[[i, i]], {i, 5}]

(* a[1, 1] + a[2, 2] + a[3, 3] + a[4, 4] + a[5, 5] *)

For[sum = 0; i = 1, i < 6, i++, sum += matrix[[i, i]]]; sum

(* a[1, 1] + a[2, 2] + a[3, 3] + a[4, 4] + a[5, 5] *)
```